# sqflite batch.commit() not working with flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I am trying to do batch update and insert with sqflite in flutter, but the commit seems to be not working. As there is no error or exception i am clueless what's going on. Below are the two methods where i am passing list and based on list id doing either update or insert in database.

```
Future<void> executeBatch(List<MusicData> _list, int version) async {
await openDb();
batch = _database.batch();
try {
  for (var i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
    buildBatch(_list[i]);
  }
  batch.commit(noResult: true);
  // Future<List> result =  batch.commit();          
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setInt('dbversion', version);

} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
}  

Future<Batch> buildBatch(MusicData musicData) async {
    await openDb();
    int id = musicData.id;
    Future<List<MusicData>> list1 =
        getSongList("select * from songs where id=$id");
    List<MusicData> list = await list1;    
    if (list.length != 0) {
      batch.rawUpdate(
          "UPDATE SONGS SET pdfpage = ?, linkid = ?, title = ?, album = ?, songURL = ?, hindiName = ?, mname = ?, msign = ?, other1 = ?, other2 = ?, ename = ?, esign = ?, language = ?,songtext = ? WHERE id = ?",
          [
            musicData.id,
            musicData.pdfpage,
            musicData.linkid,
            musicData.title,
            musicData.album,
            musicData.songURL,
            musicData.hindiName,
            musicData.mname,
            musicData.msign,
            musicData.other1,
            musicData.other2,
            musicData.ename,
            musicData.esign,
            musicData.language,
            musicData.songtext
          ]);
      print("Record updated in db $id");
      // _database.close();
    } else {
      batch.insert('SONGS', musicData.toMap());
      print("Record inserted in db $id");
    }
    // List<Map> map = await _database.rawQuery("select * from SONGS where id = '++'");
  }
```

Comment: I looked at the Database file and don't see any records are getting added. I am doing update and insert based on record exist or not.

Comment: yes.. it does.. i tried capturing result too and see valid data.

Comment: Yes.. its android device. I am using DB Browser for SQLLite to view records. When user install app it creates record i can see those, then when user relaunch i am trying to do update and insert and i don't see any of those actions happening.

Comment: No, can i do this for 200 rows? i tried starting it as Map and then converting it to string but batch doesn't accept that.

Comment: As you can see in the code, i am using for loop and building batch update/insert.

Comment: Could you please help me explain, how did you build that insert batch for 200 records?

Comment: No, it didn't work. As i am adding 200 rows that seem to be causing this issue.

Comment: problem is i don't see any error, its just that no records are getting updated in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you have trouble with batch in your funcs. First batch declared at `executeBatch` and the second at `buildBatch`, so that is two different objects, and first has no executable statements. I just have the same problem, and I found your ask. In my solution was create an object butch, I just called `_database.batch().execuste(sql);` what was incorrect. nedded:

```
batch = _database.batch(); 
batch.execute(sql);
```